# Android Studio cannot download gradle-4.0.1.pom but Chrome works

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, http-proxy

im building an andriod project via Android Studio, and get the error from openning.

---

A problem occurred configuring project ':launcher'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':launcher:classpath'.
> Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.1.
> Required by:
> project :launcher
> > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.1.
> > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/4.0.1/gradle-4.0.1.pom'.
> > Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/4.0.1/gradle-4.0.1.pom'.
> > Connection reset

- Try:

> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

---

it seems that the Android Studio cannot download gradle files from the google address, but they definitely work when i try on Chrome.

i've tried setting the ***HTTP Proxy*** to ***Auto-detect proxy*** settings" since im using VPN but still failed in downloading.

is there any setting im missing? how to get the Android Studio downloads dependencies correctly since i can download them from Chrome in a second?

thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: Make sure that there isn't a popup window somewhere in that background that is asking you if you want to trust this connection. If this is the case, click Yes there.